# How does the prestashop CMS function structure flow?

Tags: php, debugging, content-management-system, prestashop

I'm new to prestashop CMS Latest version. I would like to know how the process here occur. In the documents they described it was MVC pattern. But I'm little bit confused about classes folder as well as module folders.

As of know the controller functions are passing variable to the tpl files. But I don't know where the tpl files are loaded and the helper files are called as well as the URL structure.

If anyone know good tutorial. It will be helpful to me.

Comment: try inserting `echo '<pre>'.print_r(debug_backtrace()).'</pre>';` in the TPL for which you want to trace the execution path.

Answer (score 0):

there is some helpful links for you:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Developer+Guide
http://blog.belvg.com/prestashop-request-flow.html
http://blog.belvg.com/category/prestashop/prestashop-guide

Regards